# How to pass data in Kotlin Ktor Routing without saving the data?

Tags: kotlin, freemarker, ktor

Is it possible to pass various data in the Routing.kt class between different routes without saving the data in a database?
I'm calling a rest api in a search ui "search.ftl" and want to show the response data in another ui "found.ftl" and they're in different fields. If the data looks good the user can click "save" and then the data really go into the database.

At the end of get("field") I need to pass the data to get("found).

That's my code so far:

**Routing.kt:**

```
        route("search") {
        get {
            call.respond(FreeMarkerContent("search.ftl", model = null))
        }

        get("field") {
            
            // API-Call and json data in response
            
            val title = volumeInfoObject?.get("title")
            val author = authors?.get(0)
            val publisher = volumeInfoObject?.get("publisher")
            val pageCount = volumeInfoObject?.get("pageCount")

            client.close()
            call.respondRedirect("/search/found")
            // How to pass data to get("found")?
        }

        get("found") {
            call.respond(FreeMarkerContent("found.ftl", model = null))
        }
    }
```

**Search.ftl:**

```
<#import "_layout.ftl" as layout />
 <@layout.header>
<div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <h1 class="display-4">Search</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- // style="border:1px solid red; -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group has-search">
                <span class="fa fa-search form-control-feedback"></span>
                <form action="/search/field" method="get">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="isbn">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
       <br><br><br>
      <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="img"><img src="/static/500x900.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-8 col-sm-6">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 col-sm-6">
                        <form>
                            <fieldset disabled>
                                <legend>Book Information</legend>
                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <label for="disabledTextInput" class="form-label">Titel</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control" placeholder="Disabled input">
                                </div>
                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <label for="disabledTextInput" class="form-label">Author</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control" placeholder="Disabled input">
                                </div>
                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <label for="disabledTextInput" class="form-label">Publisher</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control" placeholder="Disabled input">
                                </div>
                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <label for="disabledTextInput" class="form-label">Pages</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control" placeholder="Disabled input">
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</@layout.header>
```

Found.ftl:

```
<#-- @ftlvariable name="book" type="com.nw.models.Book" -->
<#import "_layout.ftl" as layout />
<@layout.header>
<div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <h1 class="display-4">Search</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- // style="border:1px solid red; -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="img"><img src="/static/500x900.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-8 col-sm-6">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 col-sm-6">
                        <form action="/search/found" >
                            <legend>Book Information</legend>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="disabledTextInput" class="form-label">Titel</label>
                                <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control" name="title" value="title">
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="disabledTextInput" class="form-label">Author</label>
                                <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control" placeholder="Disabled input">
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="disabledTextInput" class="form-label">Publisher</label>
                                <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control" placeholder="Disabled input">
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="disabledTextInput" class="form-label">Pages</label>
                                <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control" placeholder="Disabled input">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</@layout.header>
```

Comment: Could you please describe what you want to implement in terms of HTTP client and an HTTP server?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman I want to call the Google Books API to search a book via ISBN and then safe it in a database (if the response json is okay).

Comment: Why can't you just call `call.respond(FreeMarkerContent("found.ftl", model = null))` inside the `get("field")`'s handler?

Comment: And how can I pass the data to the found route?

Answer (score 0):

The solution ist now like this:

I'm saving the found book directly to db and show it on my /found route:

```
call.respondRedirect("/search/found/${book?.id}")
```

On the /found page there is a delete button, so If you are not happy with the result you can directly delete the book.

```
        get("found/{id}") {
            val id = call.parameters.getOrFail<Int>("id").toInt()
            call.respond(FreeMarkerContent("edit.ftl", mapOf("book" to bookFacade.book(id))))
        }
```